# How do I show a navigation bar on top of quicklook view on ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, quicklook

I have a controller in my application that is responsible for loading a quicklook view of a csv file. The file loads just fine and I'm able to render the quicklook view without error. The problem I'm facing is now giving the user the ability to close the quicklook view.

I was trying to just render a navigation bar with a close button as part of the view that is rendering quick look. The navigation bar does not show up. I'm setting the elements after viewDidLoad. Here is the code from my controller.

```
#import "JornadaDocPreviewViewController.h"

@interface JornadaDocPreviewViewController ()

@end

@implementation JornadaDocPreviewViewController

-(id)initWidthArray:(NSArray*)array;
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        arrayOfDocuments = array;

    }

    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.dataSource = self;

    // Which item to preview
    [self setCurrentPreviewItemIndex:0];

    self.delegate = self;
    UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close"
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                   target:self
                                                                   action:@selector(closeThis)];

    NSArray *myToolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:closeButton, nil];
    self.toolbarItems = myToolbarItems;




}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller
{
    return [arrayOfDocuments count];
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewController: (QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    // Break the path into its components (filename and extension)
    NSArray *fileComponents = [[arrayOfDocuments objectAtIndex: index] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];


    // Use the filename (index 0) and the extension (index 1) to get path
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[fileComponents objectAtIndex:0] ofType:[fileComponents objectAtIndex:1]];

    NSLog(@"path %@", [fileComponents objectAtIndex:0]);

    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[arrayOfDocuments objectAtIndex: index]];
}


@end
```

------ I've tried this ----- Doesn't seem to be doing the trick

```
UIView *previewView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, self.view.frame.size.width - 20, self.view.frame.size.height - 20)];

    //[self.view addSubview:previewView];

    JornadaDocPreviewViewController *previewer = [[JornadaDocPreviewViewController alloc] initWidthArray:value];

    [previewView.window setRootViewController:previewer ];
    //[self.view bringSubviewToFront:previewView];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:previewer animated:YES];
```

Comment: How are you presenting the preview controller?

Comment: I'm adding a UIView as a subview and setting it's controller to the following controller code above.

Answer (score 0):

Don't directly show the preview controllers view. Instead, push the preview controller into the navigation controller stack and a navigation bar will automatically be shown with a done button (which will call the delegate when appropriate).

Comment: @mattwallace I rejected your edit, please edit your question with an update, thanks.